# Filtered ADO recordset Do While Not not going in order

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, recordset

For some reason when I filter a record set and then start a Do While Not loop, the loop goes through even records first, then odd...

For example, the code below:

```
sql="SELECT * FROM ProcSaleQueue WHERE Num = '" & salegrouprs("Num") & "' AND Abbr = '" & salegrouprs("Abbr") & "' AND Item_Id = '" & salegrouprs("Item_Id") & "' AND Complete IS NULL ORDER BY ProcSaleId"
salesrs.Open sql, conn,3,3
salesrs.Filter="Complete = NULL"
salesrs.MoveFirst
Do While Not salesrs.EOF
  msgbox salesrs("ProcSaleId")
  'I do some processing things in here.
  salesrs("Complete") = 1
  salesrs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Will output

72
74
73
75

Instead of

72
73
74
75

But when I remove:

```
salesrs.Filter="Complete = NULL"
```

The output is in order. I'm using .Filter instead of querying again because I have to loop through this recordset multiple times and it's a huge set so I don't want too many hits to the SQL server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By setting complete to 1 the record no longer is in scope of the filter, so you are on the next record. Try dropping the salesrs.MoveNext

Otherwise drop the filter all together and do a check if Complete

```
if salesrs("Complete") = 1 then
  salesrs.MoveNext
else
  'do your stuff
  salesrs("Complete") = 1
end if
```

Comment: Did you check that logic? Most chances that dropping the `salesrs.MoveNext` will just cause endless loop.

Comment: I ended up just checking if complete, although I was hoping to completely skip the records so I didn't have to waste time check if it's complete. However, after thinking about it, I doubt that it's much, if any, of a performance loss.

Comment: Unless you would do these checks thousands of times, no it won't be a performance loss since the records are in memory

Answer (score 0):

Your `.Filter()` is meaningless as you already select only the records where that field is NULL in the SQL itself.

If you want to put aside data you already processed, you can use local arrays e.g. to store `ProcSaleId` you can have:

```
Dim arrProcessedProcSaleId()
ReDim arrProcessedProcSaleId(-1)
Do While Not salesrs.EOF
    curProcSaleId = salesrs("ProcSaleId")
    msgbox curProcSaleId

    For x=0 To Ubound(arrProcessedProcSaleId)
        'Here arrProcessedProcSaleId(x) contains value of already processed ProcSaleId
    Next

    'I do some processing things in here.

    'store value for later use:
    ReDim Preserve arrProcessedProcSaleId(UBound(arrProcessedProcSaleId) + 1)
    arrProcessedProcSaleId(UBound(arrProcessedProcSaleId)) = curProcSaleId
    salesrs.MoveNext
Loop
salesrs.Close
Erase arrProcessedProcSaleId
```

You can have as many arrays as you like, if you got many records make sure to have `Erase` lines when done to release the memory used for the dynamic arrays.